# linking error due to the netcdf-cxx4 version of vcpkg when building under Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile, clang++, vcpkg

I have a hand-written main Makefile like this:

```
##############################################################################
################################ makefile ####################################
##############################################################################

# module name
NAME = TUDPS_test

# basic directory
DIR = .

# production switches
SW = -O3 -std=c++17 -DNDEBUG -DCLANG_1200_0_32_27_PATCH -Wno-enum-compare

# linker switches
#LSW = -std=c++17 -ferror-limit=1

# compiler
CC = clang++

# default target- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

default: $(DIR)/$(NAME)

# clean - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

clean::
    rm -f $(DIR)/*.o $(DIR)/*~ $(DIR)/$(NAME)

# define & include the necessary modules- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

# define input macros for SMS++ complete makefile, then include it
SMS++SDR = ../../SMS++
include $(SMS++SDR)/lib/makefile-c

# MILPSolver
MILPSSDR = ../../MILPSolver
include $(MILPSSDR)/makefile-s

# define input macros for UCBlock makefile, then include it
UCBckDIR = ../../UCBlock
include $(UCBckDIR)/lib/makefile

# main module (linking phase) - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

# object files
MOBJ =  $(MILPSOBJ) $(UCBckOBJ) $(SMS++OBJ)

# libraries
MLIB =  $(SMS++LIB) $(MILPSLIB) $(UCBckLIB)

$(DIR)/$(NAME): $(MOBJ) $(DIR)/test.o
    $(CC) -o $(DIR)/$(NAME) $^ $(MLIB) $(SW)

# dependencies: every .o from its .C + every recursively included .h- - - - -

# include directives
MINC =  $(SMS++INC) $(MILPSINC) $(UCBckINC)

# includes
MH =    $(SMS++H) $(MILPSH) $(UCBckH)

# compile command

$(DIR)/test.o: $(DIR)/test.cpp $(MH)
    $(CC) -c $(DIR)/test.cpp -o $@ $(MINC) $(SW)

############################ End of makefile #################################
```

that uses informations from other makefile(-c/s).

When I try to run, I obtain the following error:

```
> make
clang++ -o ./TUDPS_test ../../MILPSolver/obj/MILPSolver.o ../../MILPSolver/obj/CPXMILPSolver.o ../../MILPSolver/obj/GRBMILPSolver.o ../../MILPSolver/obj/SCIPMILPSolver.o ../../MILPSolver/obj/HiGHSMILPSolver.o ../../UCBlock/obj/BatteryUnitBlock.o ../../UCBlock/obj/DCNetworkBlock.o ../../UCBlock/obj/ECNetworkBlock.o ../../UCBlock/obj/HydroSystemUnitBlock.o ../../UCBlock/obj/HydroUnitBlock.o ../../UCBlock/obj/IntermittentUnitBlock.o ../../UCBlock/obj/NetworkBlock.o ../../UCBlock/obj/NuclearUnitBlock.o ../../UCBlock/obj/SlackUnitBlock.o ../../UCBlock/obj/ThermalUnitBlock.o ../../UCBlock/obj/ThermalUnitDPSolver.o ../../UCBlock/obj/UCBlock.o ../../UCBlock/obj/UnitBlock.o ../../SMS++/obj/AbstractBlock.o ../../SMS++/obj/BendersBFunction.o ../../SMS++/obj/BendersBlock.o ../../SMS++/obj/Block.o ../../SMS++/obj/BlockSolverConfig.o ../../SMS++/obj/BoxSolver.o ../../SMS++/obj/C05Function.o ../../SMS++/obj/ColRowSolution.o ../../SMS++/obj/ColVariable.o ../../SMS++/obj/ColVariableSolution.o ../../SMS++/obj/Configuration.o ../../SMS++/obj/Constraint.o ../../SMS++/obj/DataMapping.o ../../SMS++/obj/DQuadFunction.o ../../SMS++/obj/FRealObjective.o ../../SMS++/obj/FRowConstraint.o ../../SMS++/obj/Function.o ../../SMS++/obj/LagBFunction.o ../../SMS++/obj/LinearFunction.o ../../SMS++/obj/Objective.o ../../SMS++/obj/OneVarConstraint.o ../../SMS++/obj/PolyhedralFunction.o ../../SMS++/obj/PolyhedralFunctionBlock.o ../../SMS++/obj/RBlockConfig.o ../../SMS++/obj/RowConstraintSolution.o ../../SMS++/obj/Solver.o ../../SMS++/obj/ThinComputeInterface.o ../../SMS++/obj/Variable.o test.o -L"C:/Users/david/.vcpkg-clion/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib"  -L"C:/Users/david/.vcpkg-clion/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib" -lnetcdf -L"C:/Users/david/.vcpkg-clion/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib" -lnetcdf-cxx4 -L"C:/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studi
o1210/cplex/lib/x64_windows_msvc14/stat_mda" -lilocplex -lcplex12100 -L"C:/Users/david/.vcpkg-clion/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib" -lpthreadVC3 -L"C:/gurobi1002/win64/lib" -lgurobi100 -L"C:/Users/david/.vcpkg-clion/vcpkg/insta
lled/x64-windows/lib" -lpthreadVC3 -L"C:/HiGHS/build/RELEASE/bin" -lhighs -L"C:/Users/david/.vcpkg-clion/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib" -lpthreadVC3 -L"C:/Program Files/SCIPOptSuite 8.1.0/lib" -llibscip -lzimpl -llibsoplex  -O3 -std=c++17 -DNDEBUG -DCLANG_1200_0_32_27_PATCH -Wno-enum-compare

netcdf-cxx4.lib(ncGroup.cpp.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in MILPSolver.o
netcdf-cxx4.lib(ncVar.cpp.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in MILPSolver.o
netcdf-cxx4.lib(ncDouble.cpp.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in MILPSolver.o
```

I solved the same error in the past in a CMake project using the following:

`set(MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>")`

but I have no idea how to do the same in makefile-language, does there exist any clang-flag to do the same?

Comment: There are different msvc triplets in vcpkg that alter which runtime is used when building packages